# Showing that the Heat Equation Solution is Bounded

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have the following problem and I'm not sure how to get started, any help is appreciated!

Let u $\in C^2(U \times (0, \infty))  \cap C (\overline{U}\times[0,\infty))  $ be a solution of

\begin{cases}
u_t-u_{xx}=\sin u &\text{in}\:\:U\times (0, \infty), \newline
u=0 &\text{in} \:\: \partial U\times  (0, \infty), \newline
u=g &\text{in} \:\:U\times (t=0).
\end{cases}

Show that if $g(x) \leq 1$, then $u(x,t)\leq e^t $ for all $x \in U, t> 0.$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Seeing the bound $u(x,t) \le e^{t}$ implies, to me, some application of Gronwalls lemma. This suggests getting an energy estimate in the form of an ODE. So you can possibly try multiplying your original PDE by $u$ or some derivative of $u$ and integrating by parts, using the Dirichlet boundary condition to ensure some terms vanish, then defining an a time dependent energy $E(t)$ in terms of an integral. But I could be _totally_ wrong with this approach.

Comment: I was going to try and derive an explicit solution for the solution, and then see where that took me, but haven't even been able to do that.

Comment: Computing an explicit solution will be hard due to the $\sin(u)$ term. Try the procedure I gave you above, though it might not work.